# Url in reference clickable but with link truncated

Tags: bibtex, urls, ieee-style

I have a problem with a references using BibTeX and `IEEEbib`. In my bibliography file (in the subfolder `bib`) there is this a reference with `howpublished` that produce this output:

```
@misc{allison2012simulation,
  author = {Allison, James T.},
  title = {Simulation and Animation of a Quarter--Car Automotive Suspension Model},
  howpublished = {\url{http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35478/}},
  year = {2012}, 
  note = {[Online; accessed 25--March--2015]}
}
```

[image: Note that the URL is truncated]

Note that in the figure that the URL is clickable, but wrong because truncated at the end of line. The second part of URL is not clickable.

This is the references results that I obtain. All is right, but the link in PDF is not `http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35478/`, but only `http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/` truncated to the end of line.

The essential document is:

```
% !TeX spellcheck = en_US
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx,cite}
\usepackage{epstopdf,epsfig,tikz,mathtools,caption,subcaption,amsfonts}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\input{ushyphex}

\begin{document}
My citation~\cite{allison2012simulation}.

\bibliographystyle{bib/IEEEbib}
\bibliography{bib/suspension}

\end{document}
```

What is the way to fix it?

Comment: Yes, just a minute, but it is a simple article.

Comment: No matter if simple or complicated, a blind man cannot guess.

Comment: You are never loading `hyperref` or `url`.

Comment: And btw, this is not a *proper minimal working example8, as nobody can test it. Please invest 10 minutes in reading [How to create a minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/). Following those rules will get you prompt answers in the future.

Comment: `I couldn't open style file IEEEbib.bst`

Comment: Sorry, this isn't a standard file of LaTeX. You can find this file here: http://event.cwi.nl/witmse2012/authorskit/IEEEbib.bst.

Comment: @Johannes_B He loads the `\usepackage{url}` but not hyperref. Without trying I think to recall that this can cause such problems!?

Comment: @ManuelWeinkauf Oh, right, i overlooked package `url`. But `url` alone wouldn't make the *url*  highlighted, right?

Comment: You need to load hyperref if you want proper hyperlinks. Without it your pdf viewer will only guess where the links ends.

Comment: I have the URL **only** until the end of the line, this is my problem. Until the end of line the URL work but isn't correct because is truncated.

Comment: **Thanks to all!** With a `\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}`, and without `\usepackage{url}` I have solve the problem.

Comment: @Johannes_B I have solve the problem as described: With a `\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}` and without `\usepackage{url}`. But the question is different: my link was truncated, not unclickable.

Comment: It was clickable because the pdfreader did some guessing, but the guessing didn't work completely.

Comment: Exactly. @UlrikeFischer say me the correct way to solve the problem.